# Error caused by registerXPathNamespace() that wasn't an issue yesterday

Tags: php, api

I created a site that uses a 3rd party service to generate quotes on a service.  Up until yesterday its been working fine for about 3 weeks.  Then this morning I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function registerXPathNamespace() on boolean in [then it lists my webpage here].

Again this service has worked for several weeks no issues I've gotten back positive responses literally hundreds of times.  Then this morning for no reason the error above.  I haven't touched the code for weeks and cannot figure out why it is giving me this error.  Its like my PHP server forgot that function.
Is there something outside of my page that would cause this?

I have created a test page with all the code leading up to that line of code

...

```
   $quotedata->registerXPathNamespace('soap', 'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope');
```

'''

and it all works, I can even print out the XML generated and it looks perfect.  As a matter of fact if I take that printed XML and plug it into SOAP UI even that returns a proper response.  It is just in the line above that its breaking but that doesn't make any sense at least not to me, hopefully to someone with more experience.

Thanks.

Regards,

Frank

Comment: You need to look at the instantiation of `$quotedata` as it appears that is a boolean which normally mean FALSE indicating a failure to instantiate

Comment: So you are going to have to show us more code if you want help

Comment: OK I am going to dump in the entire page worth of code.

Comment: The commented out code is just an attempt for me to figure out what is happening

Comment: ok I assume the `$quotedata = simplexml_load_string($result);` was not commented out originally. So show us a `echo $result;` as it would appear that may not be XML or maybe not valid XML

Comment: Thanks for the help, after going round and round for most of today, turns out it was on their end, some kind of authentication issue.  As soon as they corrected it, everything started working again.